# Passing atribute from html to javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html

I think it should work, but it doesn't. I want to use simple countdown on my website posts showing how many days and hours left to post expire.
I use this html code, but when I add this to my post, I don't see it. Previously it worked fine when I specified "end_date" in JS code. But now I need to pass this as an attribute from html.

HTML Code:

```
<p id="countdown" end_date="04.02.2020"></p>
```

This is my JS code:

```
    <script>

var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");
var end_date = countdown.getAttribute("end_date");
var countDownDate = new Date(end_date).getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {


  var now = new Date().getTime();

  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);


  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "It will expire in " + days + " days and " + hours + " h ";

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Expired";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/1uLp7rj9/. Have you checked your console for errors?

Comment: It works well. What is your exact problem?

Comment: oh okay, I found the problem. When I publish the post (on wordpress), the attribute "end_date" disappears from <p> tag. But I don't know why and how to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine. To prevent Wordpress from removing your *end_date* attribute, try using the `data` attribute and target it on JS with `dataset`

```js
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");
var end_date = countdown.dataset.endDate;
var countDownDate = new Date(end_date).getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {


  var now = new Date().getTime();

  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);


  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "It will expire in " + days + " days and " + hours + " h ";

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Expired";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="countdown" data-end-date="03.14.2020"></p>
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4f60cvur/1/**